# Why Difference between dates is wrongly calculated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to subtract a date from another date to calculate difference in days. It returns difference like `735907`. Why ? It should have returned 6,7 or 10 etc.

Scenario:

I am subtracting a date which I am passing into textbox in TEXTCHANGED event from another date which I am getting from Database via SP.

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectBillSubmissionDateByBilliD]

    @pk_BillsInfo_BillID int,
    @BillSubmissionDate date output 


AS
BEGIN

          Set @BillSubmissionDate= (Select BillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate
          from BillsInfo
          Where BillsInfo.pk_BillsInfo_BillID= @pk_BillsInfo_BillID)


END
```

and then

```
Bills.ManageBillsInfo MngBillsInfo = new Bills.ManageBillsInfo();

    protected void ddlBills_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 BillID= Convert.ToInt32(ddlBills.SelectedValue);
        MngBillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate = MngBillsInfo.SelectBillSubmissionDateByBillID(BillID);     
    }

    protected void txtBoxBillPassingDate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime BillPassingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtBoxBillPassingDate.Text);
        lblDelay.Visible = true;
        lblDelay.Text = Convert.ToString( (BillPassingDate - MngBillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate).Days);
    }
}
```

Note: `MngBillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate` is of Datetime and return 1/1/0001 while debugging. Why ?

UPDATE:

A function i am calling:

```
 public DateTime SelectBillSubmissionDateByBillID(int BillID)
        {

            SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand("SelectBillSubmissionDateByBilliD", DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection());
            SqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk_BillsInfo_BillID", BillID);

            SqlParameter SqlParamBillSubmissionDate = new SqlParameter("@BillSubmissionDate", SqlDbType.Date);
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(SqlParamBillSubmissionDate);
            SqlParamBillSubmissionDate.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DatabaseConnection.CloseConnection();
            DateTime BillSubmissionDate = Convert.ToDateTime(SqlParamBillSubmissionDate.Value);

            return BillSubmissionDate;

        }
```

Comment: 1/1/0001 is `DateTime.MinValue`. That property is not being set. With that being the case, 736,000 days does sound about right. Roughly 365 * 2015.

Comment: It looks like your stored procedure returns null. Since `DateTime` is value type and can't be null, it is set to `DateTime.MinValue` that is exactly `1/1/001`

Comment: @krillgar ok sir then what to do ?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev ok sir, so what to do in order to make it right ?

Comment: Check your stored procedure and see if it is actually returning any information. I don't think you want a `SET` in there. Just have it be the `SELECT`.

Comment: @krillgar I checked, while debugging, the value is returned correctly by SP, in first EVENT and assigned to MngBillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate, but in second event, the same BillSubmissionDate is 1/1/0001

Comment: MngBillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate is a PUBLIC property with Get;Set inside Class

Comment: @krillgar yes sir,  I checked, while debugging, the value is returned correctly by SP, in first EVENT and assigned to MngBillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate, but in second event, the same BillSubmissionDate is 1/1/0001

Comment: please check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Change your sp to return the variable

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectBillSubmissionDateByBilliD]
    @pk_BillsInfo_BillID int,
    @BillSubmissionDate date output 
AS
BEGIN
      Set @BillSubmissionDate = BillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate
      from BillsInfo
      Where BillsInfo.pk_BillsInfo_BillID= @pk_BillsInfo_BillID
 END
```

I think the query is returning more than one value and the way you had it written earlier picked any one out of them. I have removed the select from your statement and now if your statement returns more than 1 value, this should give an error.

Comment: yes sir, I checked, while debugging, the value is returned correctly by SP, in first EVENT and assigned to MngBillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate, but in second event, the same BillSubmissionDate is 1/1/0001

Comment: Could it be the case that your query "Select BillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate
      from BillsInfo
      Where BillsInfo.pk_BillsInfo_BillID= @pk_BillsInfo_BillID" returns multiple rows and the select just picks one of them , and it happens to be null?

Comment: no sir, returnign only 1 record, '10/30/2015'

and please check my updated question

Comment: Yes but when it is assigned to MngBillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate in first event then it remains correct but in second event it shows '1/1/0001'.

Comment: MngBillsInfo.BillSubmissionDate is being populated only in the first event. it is not being calculated in the second event. Hence the null value. You should calculate it in the second event too.